# Android: getView() does not return correct View object

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have written custom ContactListAdapter which extends from ArrayAdapter. Let's assume that the list has just three elements. I am printing position and hashcode of View object received in each call of getView(). I have observed that view object is not returned correctly. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
private class ContactListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactItem> {
... ...
    @Override
    public View getView(int aPosition, View aConvertView, ViewGroup aParent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside ContactListAdapter.getView()");
        if(aConvertView==null) {
             Log.d(TAG, "ConvertView is null");
             // Inflate view...
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Pos: " + aPosition + " View: " + aConvertView.hashCode());
        return aConvertView;
    }
```

Here is the logs for initial view creation:

```
D/ContactsActivity(  759): Inside ContactListAdapter.getView()
D/ContactsActivity(  759): ConvertView is null
D/ContactsActivity(  759): Pos: 0 View: 1156974184
D/ContactsActivity(  759): Inside ContactListAdapter.getView()
D/ContactsActivity(  759): ConvertView is null
D/ContactsActivity(  759): Pos: 1 View: 1157007416
D/ContactsActivity(  759): Inside ContactListAdapter.getView()
D/ContactsActivity(  759): ConvertView is null
D/ContactsActivity(  759): Pos: 2 View: 1157027832
```

And logs when I click on third element in the list (Notice how the hashcode of first and last element is exchanged). My onClick method just enables few entity in the respective list entry:

```
D/ContactsActivity(  759): Inside ContactListAdapter.getView()
D/ContactsActivity(  759): Pos: 0 View: 1157027832
D/ContactsActivity(  759): Inside ContactListAdapter.getView()
D/ContactsActivity(  759): Pos: 1 View: 1157007416
D/ContactsActivity(  759): Inside ContactListAdapter.getView()
D/ContactsActivity(  759): Pos: 2 View: 1156974184
```

And logs when I click on second element:

```
D/ContactsActivity(  759): Inside ContactListAdapter.getView()
D/ContactsActivity(  759): Pos: 0 View: 1156974184
D/ContactsActivity(  759): Inside ContactListAdapter.getView()
D/ContactsActivity(  759): Pos: 1 View: 1157007416
D/ContactsActivity(  759): Inside ContactListAdapter.getView()
D/ContactsActivity(  759): Pos: 2 View: 1157027832
```

This is observed repeatedly, only the hashcode of first and last entry is exchanged every time. What might be causing this?

Comment: I'm guessing this is for a `ListView`? If that is the case then `ListView` recycles existing views - that is what `convertView` is for. If `convertView` is not `null` then you need to use it to return your new `View`.

Comment: Yes, this is Listview. Ok...this is tricky. Which means, I should call setTag() everytime getView() is called. I was doing it only when convertView is null!! I guess that's the mistake.

Answer (score 3):

convertView is used to reuse view of an adapter view, so when you are displaying a list and suppose your screen can display 5 rows at a time, then for creating views in 5 rows convertView would remain null, but when you scroll down, your adapter creates new views for your adapter view, so, sixth element in the list reuse view at position 1.

Comment: If that's the case, how ViewHolder idiom works. For example, if I want to store separate data with each element in the view using setTag().

Comment: By ViewHolder we get View objects of a view in adapter view, and set new values to each view, so it looks like both the rows are using different views.